# How can I save out hourly dates to excel?

Tags: python, excel, csv

a=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2021', end='01/01/2022', freq='h')

I have these hourly dates for the year but when I try to save it out to excel its just one ridiculously big number and what I need is 4 columns (year;month;day;hour)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be:

- Use [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to construct a `df` with respective columns.
- Use [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to write the `df` to a csv-file (also possible: directly to excel with [`df.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)).

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2021', end='01/01/2022', freq='h')

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': a.year,
                   'month': a.month,
                   'day': a.day,
                   'hour': a.hour})

print(df.head())

   year  month  day  hour
0  2021      1    1     0
1  2021      1    1     1
2  2021      1    1     2
3  2021      1    1     3
4  2021      1    1     4

df.to_csv('fname.csv')
```